# System Status reports incorrect version number after update stall

Tags: drupal, upgrade

I've tried to perform an update from 5.16.1 to 5.17, and the update script at /civicrm/upgrade?reset=1 stalled right at the end of the progress bar. After waiting many times longer than the whole update normally takes, I gave up and refreshed my browser. That page failed with "Your database has already been upgraded to CiviCRM 5.17.0".

Thinking I was in the clear, I went ahead and cleared sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/ and set the site live again. Only now I've noticed System Status is reporting that I'm still running 5.16.1 and need an upgrade. In the footer at the bottom of the page it correctly reports 5.17.

Is this likely to be a problem, and should I do anything to fix it? Or should I just wait for the next update and hope that clears it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the upgrade stalled out partway through, you'd get a message that you were partially upgraded - so my guess is that the only thing that didn't happen was that `version-msgs-cache.json` didn't get deleted.

That file will update on its own after three days, but you can also find it and delete it.  You may want to check the permissions/ownership on it, in case it's owned by the wrong user, and that caused the upgrade to hang.  That would indicate a deeper issue to deal with.

Comment: I've found at version-msgs-cache.json. Could that be the one?

Comment: Looks like it is. Thanks!